# Building a flight controller

Tags: pcb-design, circuit-design, usb, stm32, pwm

I am new to electrical engineering and am having a very hard time trying to build my own flight controller. I think I have the basic idea as I am going off someone else's schematic. I am using easyEDA as then I can get the board fully manufactured by them so I can't screw up the soldering.
I think this may work but I need to know how I am going to program it, it's for a model rocket with thrust vector control. Everyone I see buy an external object like the ST Link but I want to just plug it into my computer and write the program through that, like a drone flight computer. I also need to know if the pins that are connected to servo 1, 2, and 3 are actually PWM as the other person uses them for motors and I'm not sure if they will work with servos. The MCU chip datasheet is [here](https://www.st.com/resource/en/programming_manual/dm00046982-stm32-cortex-m4-mcus-and-mpus-programming-manual-stmicroelectronics.pdf).

Please look over my schematic image and say if it's right or what I need to change. Any help will be great as I am now at a dead end and am starting to loose my mind.

[image: this is what I've got so far.]

Comment: I'm very reluctantly voting to close.  Reluctant because you're new and it's a good subject for discussion.  But voting to close because StackExchange is a strict _question and answer_ site, where we ask you to write a self-contained question that has a small set of answers.  What you need is a wide-ranging discussion over all of your design choices.  I can only personally recommend reddit.com/r/ece, but there may be other discussion fora out there.

Comment: If you do get to the point where you're asking specific questions (like "how do I generate a servo pulse from an STM32F405?") then you are _very welcome_ to ask them here.

Comment: _"I'm not sure if they will work with servos."_ - which servos do you intend to use?

Answer (score 3):

This is a substantial project for someone who is new to electronics; be ready to break it down into smaller chunks and address each one in turn.

Servos are typically controlled using a 1-2ms pulse, which is much like PWM but not exactly PWM.  A 1ms pulse instructs the servo to move to one and of its travel, 2ms moves to the other end and 1.5ms is in the middle.  Unlike true PWM though, the servo doesn’t much care about the ‘off’ time between the pulses (often about 20ms) whereas for PWM the ratio of on:off time is important and the pulse frequency is typically less important.  So a PWM output can drive a servo provided that the frequency can be set to something appropriate (50 to 500Hz) and you keep the ‘on’ period in the 1-2ms range.

Comment: Sorry I meant to write this as a comment rather than an answer but it’s too long for a comment.  Since it does attempt to answer the question in part I’ll leave it here unless there’s significant resistance.

Answer (score 0):

Two big mistakes.

1. Servos will not work if supplied from 3.3V
2. Servo requires much more current than your LDO can supply (and remember that it will have very high pick consumption + it will increase with load).

You will need a separate supply path for servos.

You forgot about pull-up I2C resistors (internal are too weak for this aplication).

It will "work" if you correct those mistakes but it will not survive too long

> The MCU chip datasheet is here.

No, this document is useless here. It is core documentation useful for compiler and RTOS developers. Look for the datasheet (where pin assignments are listed) and `Reference Manual` which documents the peripherals.